# Reading after ileInputStream(name, boolean)

Tags: java

I have written program which should save object ArrayList, then read this and add new index. Physically, each new entry is added to the file but I can see only first entry after runnning. I do not know. The one think I know is I've to write once again the same code but in one class.

Save:

```
class Zapis {
    private Operacje op = new Operacje();
    private GregorianCalendar gregorianCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    private Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    private ArrayList<String> x = new ArrayList<String>();
    private Odczyt historia = new Odczyt();

public void test() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, NullPointerException {
    try {
        op.dzien = String.format("%tc", gregorianCalendar);
        op.kwota = scanner.nextInt();
        x.add(op.toString());
        ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("costam.bin",true));
        objectOutputStream.writeObject(x);
        objectOutputStream.close();
        ;
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("costam.bin",true));
        op.dzien = String.format("%tc", gregorianCalendar);
        op.kwota = scanner.nextInt();
        x.add(op.toString());
        objectOutputStream.writeObject(x);
        objectOutputStream.close();
    }
}
```

Read:

```
public class Odczyt {

public static ArrayList<String> array;

public void test() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("costam.bin"));
    array = (ArrayList<String>) objectInputStream.readObject();
    int k = array.size();
    System.out.println(k);
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        System.out.println(array.get(i));
    }
    objectInputStream.close();
}
```

Comment: You are writing a file with several array lists saved one after another. Then you read the first one. Perhaps you shouldn't be opening the file stream in append mode.

Comment: you mean that I should create two tables and the results of one move to another and then read the second?

Comment: I don't know what tables you are referring to. But you seem to have one of two mistakes: (1) You think that writing several array lists one after another into an object stream is equivalent to having one big array list with all their contents, or (2) You are using the "append" flag in `FileOutputStream` when you actually want to write a new, bigger ArrayList *instead* of the old small one that is in the file.

Comment: Actually I thought about both. So can you propose me something what coud I do to make it works?

Comment: Start by not using the append flag and see if that works better for you.

Comment: I did but it still doesn't work. I didn't notice any difference

Comment: So it seems you need to read the list from the file, close the file, add the new data to the list, and save it back to the file (without append). Frankly - I wouldn't use an object stream at all - if you can write the information into the file in text format, you'll be able to append it properly.

Comment: I did the first tip. I changed everything into one class and see what did I create. I'll paste my code in new post. Everything is working. Thank you mate!

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Wszystko {
private static Operacje op = new Operacje();
private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
private static GregorianCalendar gregorianCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
private static ArrayList<String> array;

public static void test() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    try {
        wczytaj();
        ustawOp();
        dodajDoArray();
        wydrukuj();
        zapisz();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("costam.bin"));
        op.dzien = String.format("%tc", gregorianCalendar);
        op.kwota = scanner.nextInt();
        array.add(op.toString());
        objectOutputStream.writeObject(array);
        objectOutputStream.close();
    }
}

public static void wczytaj() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("costam.bin"));
    array = (ArrayList<String>) objectInputStream.readObject();
}
public static void ustawOp(){ op.dzien = String.format("%tc", gregorianCalendar);
    op.kwota = scanner.nextInt();}
public static void dodajDoArray(){
    array.add(op.toString());}
public static void wydrukuj(){
    int s = array.size();
    for(int i =0; i<s; i++){
        System.out.println(array.get(i));
    }
}
public static void zapisz() throws IOException {
    ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("costam.bin",true));
    objectOutputStream.writeObject(array);
    objectOutputStream.close();}

}
```

Everything is working:D